# Getting the error "Cannot find module './commands'" while trying to run cypress tests

Tags: cypress, uncaught-exception, cypress-configuration

When I'm trying to run cypress test I'm getting this error:

> The following error originated from your test code, not from Cypress.
>
> \> Cannot find module './commands'
>
> When Cypress detects uncaught errors originating from your test code it will automatically fail the current test.
>
> Cypress could not associate this error to any specific test.
>
> We dynamically generated a new test to display this failure.

I was expecting my tests to run, and I've tried to create an index.js in the support folder with:

```
import './commands'

Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
  return false;
})
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

When I had this issue it was because I tried to import from the wrong file.

Instead of importing in the test file, commands should be imported into `/cypress/support/e2e(.js|.ts)` file.

Ref [Custom Commands](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands)

> We recommend defining queries is in your cypress/support/commands.js file, since it is loaded before any test files are evaluated via an import statement in the supportFile.

That way they are available in ***any*** test that requires them. This is because the  `/cypress/support/e2e.js` file is automatically integrated into the start of any and all test runs.